# generate unique id based on timestamp laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create uniqueid based on timestamps in laravel.
In laravel, Timestamps become 2 column, namely created_at and updated_at.
like this [timestamps laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umXWw.png)

I want to combine created_at and updated_at column for unique id without dash (-) and (:).
sample output (for first row in screenshot): 2016091510453920160915104539

I used this code for $transid column:

```
public function insertFund($request,$lender, $type)
{
    $transid = timestamp();  
    $fund = $this->fund->create([
        'transid' => $transid
    ]);
    return $fund;
}
```

But, i get error when submit.
is it possible to write code for this here?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What error are you getting? And what is the datatype transid column in DB table?

Comment: datatype transid is text

Comment: Perhaps a mutator on transid could get you what you need. Overload the transid attribute by defining a setTransidAttribute method on your model and then use the updated and created at fields to store in transid? Hopefully I'm understanding you correctly here.

Answer (score 2):

i try this, and it works for me

```
$now = Carbon::now();
$unique_code = $now->format('YmdHisu')
```

the output is

```
20180410171800873514
```

if you parse you can see 2018 04 10 17:18:00 873514

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do. I understood that you want to create a record and fill the transid with concatenated timestamps.
The timestamps before the are empty as the record hasn't created yet.
In your case i would create the record and after that i would get the timestamps and update the same record. 
Example code:

```
$fund = Fund::create($input);
$transid = $fund->created_at.$fund->updated_at;
$fund->transid = $transid;
$fund->update();
```

If this is not what you are trying to do , provide more information in order to help.

Comment: I just follow your instruction, but there's eror like this : 
ErrorException in AccountController.php line 788:
Undefined variable: input

Comment: in your case the input is passed to the $request variable. so replace my $input parameter with $request.

Comment: i just use $transid = date("Ymd")."1".time(); for my id